# RVM warning on install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have been using ruby globally on my macOSX 10.14.6 with homebrew and chruby and that has been causing issues when different apps and gem updates. A friend pointed me to RVM so I can isolate my projects.

Would someone mind explaining if this warning needs to fixed? I'm not entirely familiar with why or how?

I installed RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` and added "`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`" to my bash_profile

Then ran `rvm install 2.5.1`

I got this in my log:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/MYNAME/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use 2.5.1
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.5.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
```

**Would someone mind explaining if this warning needs to fixed? I'm not entirely familiar with why or how?**

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute

`echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile`

you shouldn't need to do it again. That line appends the necessary file inclusion information RVM into your `.bash_profile`. If you are using `bash` (as opposed to zsh, ksh, csh, tcsh or any other shell), then RVM will be accessible each time you open a new session. If you are using a different shell, that line may need to be in a different startup file. For example, if you are using zsh, then you'll probably want to append it to your `~/.zshrc` file.

Having done this, simply running `rvm --default use 2.5.1` once should ensure that you have the desired version of Ruby by default. Note, you should not need to add this line to your `.bash_profile` or similar.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!